# Deletion of big amount of lines

Tags: mysql, batch-file, optimization

I have 3 tables MyISAM tables with about 100 million lines each.

```
Table1 structure is (region, id,timestamp)
Table2 structure is (region, id, data1, data2)
Table3 structure is (region, id, data3, data4)

Table1 PK is (region,id)
Table2 PK is (region,id,data1)
Table3 PK is (region,id,data3)
```

Each table size is about 3Gb

I want to delete all the lines for which (region, id) is associated to a timestamp more than 7 days ago. (about 15% of the table)

I tried two methods, none of them is satisfying.

- First I did some multi-tables delete using JOIN. 12hours later, it was still running.
- Second, I did a select on the first table, to get all (region,id) I have to delete, and then do delete in batches of 10,000 on each of the tables. For this, the syntax is basically : DELETE FROM table WHERE (region,id) IN ((region1,id1),(region1,id2)...) This method seems really slow (60s per request), and, when I do an EXPLAIN, the PK are not used (!!).

I tried to disable the indices on table2 and table3, but it didn't seem to drastically improve the performances of those queries.

Moreover, if the query takes too much time, I would like to be able to have it not locking the table it's working on, so that I can do other operations (INSERT only) on this table at the same time.

So, do you have any suggestion, or are there any best practice to do that?

Comment: can you do this operation offline and move to server when operation is ready?

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean by "doing this operation offline"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a cursor, which could be used to delete one record at a time? For example,

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS delete_using_cursor$$
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_using_cursor()
BEGIN
declare done int default false;
declare pk int;
declare c cursor for select [id] from [table] where [conditions];
declare continue handler for not found set done = true;
set @strSQL = 'delete from [table] where [id] = ?';
prepare stmt from @strSQL;
open c;
read_loop: loop
  fetch c into pk;
  if done then
    leave read_loop;
  end if;
  set @pk = pk;
  execute stmt using @pk;
end loop;
close c;
deallocate prepare stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```